# How to check a text box for a certain character and replace with a different string in the same spot

Tags: vb.net, textbox, translation, letter

I am working on a little morse code translation project and I cannot figure out how to detect when a certain key is in a textbox and replace it with the corresponding morse code dots and dashes in the correct spot.

For example if you type in "a b c" then i would like the program to check and put

".-  -...  -.-."

but it also needs to be dynamic so if you change up the order of your letters it can update the translation.

as of right now i have a key checking system where you can only type in one forward line and if you mess up you have to clear the whole box. thank you!

Comment: It doesn't sound like what you're suggesting is practical. If the user were to enter one character and you replaced it with it's Morse code equivalent, what's to stop the user then positioning the caret within that multi-character code and typing another character, thus creating nonsense? You'd have to prevent the user enter regular characters anywhere but between encoded characters, which would be messy. I'd suggest that you have two `TextBoxes`. The user enters regular text into the first and you display the translation in the second that is read-only. TBC...

Comment: You can then simply handle the `TextChanged` event of the first `TextBox` and translate the whole text every time. It will be very quick so performance won't be an issue and it means that you don't have to care where the user enters a character. It also means that they won't have to be able to read the Morse code to remember what they typed in.

Comment: Of course, another option would be to [use a dedicated font for Morse code](https://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+morse+code+font&form=EDGTCT&qs=PF&cvid=9a12b58a2fae41a2b61662f4fa17ad24&refig=96229b880dc04bafc47b5135d9ab2b20&cc=AU&setlang=en-GB&elv=AXK1c4IvZoNqPoPnS%21QRLOMzsfv0XStLE1tfEjLKXSEreilFvWCxDnkpSmX3S2KdoKFOc4mh9pkzEpEpTtJsboJ52vtXsvS0sSX2Fnk3inBl). That way, you wouldn't have to do any translation at all.  That said, if the user were to copy and paste, they'd have to be using that same font where they pasted or they'd get the untranslated text, so that might not be any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a basic example of what I was suggesting in my comments above, i.e. using two separate `TextBoxes` and translating the whole text every time:

```
Private morseCodeDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Char, String) From {{"a"c, ".-"},
                                                                     {"b"c, "-..."},
                                                                     {"c"c, "-.-."}}

Private Sub inputTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles inputTextBox.TextChanged
    outputTextBox.Text = String.Join(" ",
                                     inputTextBox.Text.
                                                  ToLower().
                                                  Select(Function(ch) morseCodeDictionary(ch)))
End Sub
```

Here's an implementation that doesn't use LINQ, so may be more understandable:

```
Private Sub inputTextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles inputTextBox.TextChanged
    Dim characterStrings As New List(Of String)

    For Each ch As Char In inputTextBox.Text
        characterStrings.Add(morseCodeDictionary(ch))
    Next

    outputTextBox.Text = String.Join(" ", characterStrings)
End Sub
```

Comment: The code I provided creates an output `String` with a single space between each Morse character. I'm not sure how you're representing word boundaries but one option might be to add an entry to the `Dictionary` where the key is the space character and the value is an empty `String`. That way, every space in the input will result in two spaces between Morse characters in the output, which may well be an appropriate word boundary.

Comment: I am using your code and it works thank you! The only problem is it throws an error when you press any key that isnt in the dictionary.

Comment: I did say that this was a basic example.  It just shows the general principle and it does address your original question, but you can modify the code to provide whatever additional functionality you need or want. With regard to invalid characters, I can think of multiple ways to handle them. The simplest would involve simply adding a filter before the `Select` call to ignore those characters: `Where(Function(ch) morseCodeDictionary.ContainsKey(ch)).`. That would leave the invalid characters in the input but ignore them in the output.

Comment: You might also want to remove invalid characters from the output or prevent their being entered in the first place or display an error message or something else.  You need to decide how you want the app to work and then write the code accordingly.